# How can I move the location of a virtualenv via virtualenvwrapper to a usb drive attached to a raspberry pi running DietPi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to setup a headless RaspberryPi 1B+ to run a couple of python scripts via cron. I'm aware that SD cards tend to be the weak spot so I've got an old 60Gb SSD in an usb enclosure mounted as /mnt/usb-ssd1.

Python3 is installed and working; I've installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper via pip3.

I'm able to make and remove virtual environments via the mkvirtualenv and rmvirtualenv commands so long as my WORKON_HOME var is set to a location on the SD card. I'm able to make new folders on the SSD via the mkdir command so I have permission to write to the SSD.

However when I switch the location of WORKON_HOME to be on the SSD my mkvirtualenv command gives the following error:

" OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/usr/bin/python3' -> '/mnt/usb-ssd1/.virtualenvs/test1/bin/python' "

Distro: DietPi

any ideas? I've googled extensively but must be asking the wrong question

Thanks